# Problem with django-RESTframework-Tutorial

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get familiar with django-RESTframeworks, therefore I started the official tutorial, to create a Test-API.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#quickstart

When finally starting the API on my Windows via [CMD] "pyhon manage.py runserver", I get an error code on the command line, which you will see below.

I also want to add, that unfortunately, there is some ambiguity in the descriptions in the tutorial, at least from the viewpoint of a beginner, i.e. it's not always certain whether the corresponding code in the tutorial
needs to be added in a module or replace all or part of the code in the modules.

Therefore, I tried implementing the directions of the tutorial in various ways, always with the same end result.

I'm running the code in a virtual env, where i've installed Django 1.11., so there shouldn't be an issue with different Django versions.

```
C:\Users\Rolimar\projects\djREST_tut>workon djresttut
(djresttut) C:\Users\Rolimar\projects\djREST_tut>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000004CBF978>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\Envs\djresttut\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Rolima\projects\djREST_tut\tutorial\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
from django.urls import include, path
ImportError: cannot import name include
```

And here my codes, I tried to copy from the tutorial:

"serializers.py"

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')
```

"views.py"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from tutorial.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

"urls.py"

```
            """tutorial URL Configuration

            The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
                https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
            Examples:
            Function views
                1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
                2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
            Class-based views
                1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
                2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
            Including another URLconf
                1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
                2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
            """
            from django.conf.urls import url
            from django.contrib import admin

            from django.urls import include, path
            from rest_framework import routers
            from tutorial.quickstart import views

            router = routers.DefaultRouter()
            router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
            router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

            urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('', include(router.urls)),
                path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
            ]
```

in "settings.py", where I added 'rest_framework'

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    'rest_framework',
]
```

and where I also added the following code in the very end:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are using **django<2.0** but following tutorials which are written in **django>2.0**. From django 2.0, `include` has been moved to `django.urls`, before it resided in `django.conf.urls`([changelog reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax)). So you need to update your `urls.py` like this:

```
        from django.conf.urls import url, include
        from django.contrib import admin
        from rest_framework import routers
        from tutorial.quickstart import views

        router = routers.DefaultRouter()
        router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
        router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
            url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
            url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
        ]
```

You can't use `path` as well, because it was [introduced in django 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax) as well.

Or you can move to **django>2.0**, but in that case you have to remove `from django.conf.urls import url` and use `from django.urls import url`.

Comment: thank you!
i wonder, why pip installed django 1.11 instead of django 2.x...
maybe, because i'm using python2.7?